# C++11 Correct usage of smart pointers in a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I am trying to use some new design techniques to implement a linked list,

but I can't seem to figure out just the right way to do it .

The techniques are smart pointers and the null object pattern .

The problems I'm having are with the destruction of the entire list ,

I had one implementation where it did not destruct a few objects,

now I seem to have a cyclic problem and it does not exit at all.

Follows the code:

linkedlist.h

```
    #pragma once
    #include <memory>
    #include "node.h"

    class LinkedList {
    public:
        LinkedList() : m_size(0), head(nullptr) {};
        void addNode(int value);
        void removeNode(int index);
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<Node> getNodeAtIndex(int index);
        std::shared_ptr<Node> getLastNode();
        void _addNode(int value);
        inline void increaseSize() { ++m_size; }
        inline void decreaseSize() { --m_size; }
    private:
        size_t m_size;
        std::shared_ptr<Node> head;
    };
```

linkedlist.cpp

```
    #include "linkedlist.h"

    void LinkedList::addNode(int value) {
        _addNode(value);
        increaseSize();
    }

    void LinkedList::_addNode(int value) {
        if (nullptr == head) {
            head = std::make_shared<Node>(Node(value));
            return;
        }
        std::shared_ptr<Node> tail = getLastNode();
        std::shared_ptr<Node> nextNode = std::make_shared<Node>(Node(value));
        nextNode->setPrevious(tail);
        tail->setNext(nextNode);
    }

    void LinkedList::removeNode(int index) {
        std::shared_ptr<Node> node = getNodeAtIndex(index);
        node->getNext()->setPrevious(node->getPrevious());
        node->getPrevious()->setNext(node->getNext());
        decreaseSize();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Node> LinkedList::getNodeAtIndex(int index) {
        std::shared_ptr<Node> node = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i) {
            node = node->getNext();
        }
        return node;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Node> LinkedList::getLastNode() {
        return getNodeAtIndex(m_size-1);
    }
```

Node.h

```
    #pragma once
    #include <memory>

    class Node {
    public:
        Node() : value(0), next(nullptr), previous(nullptr) {};
        Node(int value) : value(value) {};
        ~Node() { printf("%d", value); };
        std::shared_ptr<Node> getNext();
        virtual void setNext(std::shared_ptr<Node> newNext);
        std::shared_ptr<Node> getPrevious();
        virtual void setPrevious(std::shared_ptr<Node> newPrevious);
    private:
        int value;
        std::shared_ptr<Node> next;
        std::shared_ptr<Node> previous;
    };

    class NullNode : public Node {
    public:
        virtual void setNext(Node* newNext) {};
        virtual void setPrevious(Node* newPrevious) {};
    };
```

node.cpp

```
    #include "node.h"

    std::shared_ptr<Node> Node::getNext() {
        if (nullptr == next) {
            return std::shared_ptr<Node>(new NullNode);
        }
        return next;
    }

    void Node::setNext(std::shared_ptr<Node> newNext) {
        next = newNext;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Node> Node::getPrevious() {
        if (nullptr == previous) {
            return std::shared_ptr<Node>(new NullNode);
        }
        return previous;
    }

    void Node::setPrevious(std::shared_ptr<Node> newPrevious) {
        previous = newPrevious;
    }
```

main.cpp

```
    #include "linkedlist.h"

    void addToList() {
        LinkedList list;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            list.addNode(i);
        }
        for (int i = 99; i >= 0; ++i) {
            list.removeNode(i);
        }
    }

    int main() {
        addToList();
    }
```

I want to understand where did I go wrong - is it with the return of the shared_ptr's,

is it the choice of the shared_ptr against weak / unique ?

And of course - how do I make this code sample work properly .

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 99; i >= 0; ++i) {
    list.removeNode(i);
}
```

When `i` starts out as `99` and you only add to it (`++i`), bad things are probably going to happen before it overflows. You probably meant `--i`.

You should consider writing it like this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    list.removeNode(0);
}
```

Or:

```
while (!list.empty()) list.removeNode(0);
```

The last way requires you to expose the size of the container or add the requsite `empty()` function to test if the list is empty.

---

If you had run your program in a debugger, it would have helped you discover this problem on your own. You should learn how to use a debugger :)